# Компиляция со свойствами /MD /MT

Tags: c++, visual-c++

У меня есть проект, в которой я подтащил несколько либ, их компилял из сорсов сам. Впоследствии возникли ошибки линковки и это было связано с тем, что некоторые либы были собраны с /MT а некоторые с /MD, собственно почитав документацию не до конца разобрался почему это возникает. Как я понял есть msvs либа от которой зависят библиотеки, и в случае с MT они компиляют код в свой объектник, в случае с MD сохраняют в объектник имя DLL, которое подтянут в рантайме, если так не понимаю почему тогда возникает конфликт.(либо я вообще всё понял неправильно)).

Comment: Насколько я знаю, смешивание разных видов стандартной библиотеки в принципе возможно. Покажите примеры ошибок линковки.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, в принципе может и возможно, но на практике линкер выдает ошибки. Если вы знаете как можно подключить MD библиотеку к MT программе (или наоборот), поделитесь. Не то чтобы это стоило практиковать, но просто интересно.

Comment: @freim Ну, у меня на простых тестовых проектах все само по себе работает в любых комбинациях. Ничего особенного делать не надо. Единственное что, если изменить параметр MT/MD и не сделать пересборку проекта, на первой попытке сборки выдает несколько ошибок "повторное определение". На второй попытке уже нормально собирается (видимо, какой-то мусор остается в объектных файлах). Может автор на ту же проблему натыкается.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, странно, вот у меня не так давно не собиралась одна из конфигураций проекта с wxWidgets, как раз из-за этого. Причем solution rebuild не помог, пришлось разбираться. Может, этот эффект только с большими библиотеками проявляется? Скорее всего, правду мы узнаем только тогда, когда у кого-нибудь появится избыток лишнего времени для исследования этого важного вопроса. :)